# How would I create an arch?

Tags: modeling, workflow

Is there a simple way to create an arch? Different type of arches on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arch#Types_of_arches).
I'm interested in the *Round arch* or *Elliptical arch* type of arches.

Comment: Are you after a solid arch or a made of bricks arch?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use an array + the *simple deform modifier*.

1. Start with a cube, this will be your "brick":
   [image]
2. add an array modifier, make it as long as you want bricks. make them go up on the `Z` axis
   [image]
3. add a *simple deform* modifier.
4. set the type to bend.
5. set the angle to `180`
6. Add an empty at the origin of your object
   [image]
7. Rotate it by 90 degrees on the `Y` axis.
8. Set it to the origin in the bend modifier
9. Move it away from your object to control the width of your arch, you may have to try multiple axis.
   [image]
   **GIF**

[image]

Answer (score 23):

Use the **[warp](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.80/modeling/meshes/editing/transform/warp.html#warp)** tool.

Take a cube. Stretch it, add a few loop cuts, then move the cursor to where you want the center of the arch, and use the warp tool:

[image]

Answer (score 18):

You can do this by modeling one section and then add an array modifier using a rotated empty to wrap it around a point, creating an arch.

[image]

settings of the array modifier on the arch section:

[image]

Example of this type of arch in a scene:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I really like your bottom image.

Answer (score 13):

You can also do this by modeling a brick, setting the cursor to center, and using the spin tool.

(model the brick, set cursor to center)

[image]

Use spin tool to create arch.

[image]

Comment: Your normals are reversed!

Comment: I see this approach as being useful for high poly modeling, but for games (which I'm interested in), the half circle extrude method seems like a better approach.

Answer (score 11):

You can achieve this with an array and a curve modifier.

1. Add a curve; then  model it in to what ever shape arch you want.
2. On the object that will be repeated across the arch, add the two modifiers an array and a curve.
   [image: modifiers]

Set the array modifier's *Fit Type* to *Fit Curve*, then select the curve. Then set the Curve modifier's *Object* to be the same curve.

Answer (score 10):

Using a circle as a starting point. Delete half of the vertices. Place the cursor on the center of the arc and extrude and scale keeping the pivot point on the 3D cursor.

[image]

Extrude on the Z axis. Then you can use the inset tool <kbd>I</kbd> (with idividual faces on) to create
the edge of the bricks.

[image]

Comment: I like this method because it doesn't create a bunch of loose meshes and lends itself to low poly game object modeling. You can skip the last step if you need to use normal maps instead of extruded geometry.

Answer (score 8):

Using the **Bridge Edge Loops** tool.

- Create a plane
- Duplicate
- Move newly created plane to the place you want the arc to end
- Select all and rotate 180 degrees
- Use Bridge edge loops and adjust the number of cuts.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

You can create a arch from a circle, or cylinder.

1. Start by deleting the bottom half of the vertices.
2. If you want a symmetrical arch add a mirror modifier and delete half of the vertices.
3. Model the circle in to the arch shape you want.

[image: circle with mirror modifier]

Answer (score 7):

There is an addon available in [contrib](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/BAC/) called Building Objects that can create a brick wall which can include openings with arched tops (and bottoms). By setting the start and end of the wall to small values you can still get the arch with some easy to remove bricks on the side.

[image]

The block width alters the size of the pieces over the arch.

[image]

A curve size greater than 2.0 gives you a pointed arch.

[image]

Contrib addons aren't included with official release builds of blender but are normally included with [daily builds](https://builder.blender.org/download/) and many [graphicall builds](http://graphicall.org/) and the latest version can be downloaded [from here](https://git.blender.org/gitweb/gitweb.cgi/blender-addons-contrib.git/snapshot/HEAD.tar.gz).