# I want to curve an object like a roller coaster using a path

Tags: objects, bezier-curves

I want to curve an object to make a path like a roller coaster.

I just made ​​the basic shape (wooden tablet, left and right binary).

How to curve it?

Thank you so much.

[image: basic shape]

Comment: Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34598/how-to-curve-my-mesh, also - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21698/how-would-i-create-an-arch

Comment: As an option, you can use the array and curve modifiers to place the sleepers along the curve (like in this tutorial - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QvIxyyGBlDw) and add rails by using the bevel object and the same curve.

Answer (score 3):

**Important**

Make sure your track model's origin is moved to align exactly on the edge of the model. The modifier will depend on the origin's Position to make duplicate and alignment.

[image]

1. Use the Array modifier to create copies of the track model.
2. Create a bezier curve representing the curve and length of track.
3. Add a Curve Deform Modifier and target the bezier path curve object.

   [image]

The blend file ...

[image]

**Extra Note**
Instead of "Fixed Count" use "Fit Curve" on the array modifier *Fit type* drop down menu to improve control to the duplication of the mesh according to the length of the curve.

Comment: In the Array modifier enable *Merge* so you get smooth surface everywhere and you don't have artifacts where the tiles meet!

Comment: Thanks @hawkenfox, with your answer and Blender file I found what I was searching for.