# How to join this arc

Tags: modeling

I have a u shape and i want that 2 vertex join and make a arc. In the image i have shown the u shape black color and red color arc. Can we join the 2 green color pointed vertex and make a arc. Any method to join them and make a arc quick and simple[image]

Comment: maybe related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21698/how-would-i-create-an-arch/21707#21707

Comment: Remove doubles is very handy when merging many different objects in various ways

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [**Spin**](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/editing/duplicating/spin.html) tool and create the arc-shaped top based on the existing geometry.

1. Select top vertices which should serve as a base for the arc. Snap cursor to them with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> menu. Note that spinning will happen based on 3D cursor position and the current orientation of the view in the viewport.
2. Deselect one of the vertices leaving only one selected (to make spin happen from one origin).
3. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to execute the tool (or find it on the *Toolshelf*). Adjust *Angle* in operator's options to 180 degrees and set amount of steps according to your mesh.
4. Make sure to remove double vertices with <kbd>W</kbd> menu.

   [image: GIF create arc]

Answer (score 1):

- Add circle
  [image]
- Select the left vertex and <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>s</kbd> and *cursor to selected*
  [image]
- Choose 3dcursor as pivot point
  [image]
- Select vertices
  [image]
- Then scale with -1 along the x-axis
- Select the right vertex and <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>s</kbd> and *cursor to selected*
  [image]
- Select vertices
  [image]
- Then scale with -1 along the x-axis
  [image]

Comment: Thanks for replying but i have made the u shape just want to join the top 2 vertex and make arc shape. I tried the spin also but i want much more flexible then that

Comment: do you already have the arc? if that's the case, then you can merge with alt+m in edit mode

Comment: I have the u shape only and want to create that arc with the u shape top 2 vertex as shown in image

Comment: what is the radius of the arc?