# How would i curve panels like this?

Tags: modeling

[image]

How would i curve panels on a surface like this?
I am making a lobby for a building and i am trying to model this in a cleaner way.[image]

Comment: start with the arch around the window and then extrude it out.

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21698/how-would-i-create-an-arch

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may do it using a ***Spin Tool***. In *right view* add a *single vertex* and extrude it creating the arch's profile. In *Object Mode* press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to place the cursor in the center of a grid. In *Edit Mode* grab the profile and translate it along the Z axis. Press the ***Spin*** button in a *tool shelf*. Your arch is ready.
[image]

You can model a niche in the same way. After spinning it divide it using loopcuts (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>). Then extrude single segments downwards as pictured below. You have a clean geometry to add creasing loopcuts for the *Subsurf Modifier*.
[image]

Finally join the meshes with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>, remove doubles and give the object a *Mirror Modifier*.

Answer (score 0):

Add some loopcuts (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>) (use mousewheel after entering loopcut move to increase the number of loopcuts) or subdivition on the faces, active propostional editing>connected and move the bottom edge (<kbd>G</kbd>) (and lock to an axis if prefered). Use the mousewheel to increase/decrease the effect radius while moving.

[image]

After that, you can add some bevel (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>) to the edge for the final curve (in this case, you would probably prefer to set **Amount type** to **Width** in bevel tool options as well).

[image]

PS: I would suggest using mirror modifier for such symmetrical projects:

[image]

Comment: But how do i do the colorful designs on the arch?