# Boolean this made arch wtih a plane

Tags: modifiers

I'm trying to boolean this made arch wtih the plane, goal is to the remove the middle part of the wall inside Arch to make is open. Thx

[image]

Comment: hello, please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Hello @moonboots :). Having a .blend is always useful, but perhaps recommend some other service for these temporary files (like [WeTransfer](https://wetransfer.com/)). Blend-Exchange is meant specifically for long-term storage :).

Comment: Hi @Moonboots just sent it

Comment: @ Jachym Michal, ok, I thought it was wrong to recommend something else than blend exchange

Comment: @ Jason, I can't see the link, please share the link here

Comment: oops sorry here it is..

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=5zAQVPde" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/5zAQVPde/)

Comment: It seems so simple but as I am new to blender I cant figure it out

Comment: Trv to avoid booleans for things that can be modeled. Here's a link on many ways to crreate archs : [How would I create an arch?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21698/how-would-i-create-an-arch)

Answer (score 2):

You need to model the part you want removed as the "tool" for the boolean modifier.

In the image, if I Boolean Difference the arch from the plane, it creates a cutout of the arch in the plane as you can see on the left. If you only want the inside part of the arch to be removed from the plane you have to model that part as the tool for the boolean modifier, as on the right.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that, I'm trying it out to see if it works

Comment: @Jason did this work for you? If so, mark it as answered so others can find it.